# Magento 2 | Can't reset customer password and change name

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am listening to following event with an observer:

> customer_address_save_after

**The problem:**
Whenever the customer wants to reset the password or change his name or email address this observer is being executed and magento says the customer couldn't be saved.

The observer itself doesn't throw an error.

Any suggestion what to do?

Comment: are you trying to reset the password from admin? Also, this observer has nothing to do with reset password or change of name or email, until you are trying to create customer within a custom module.

Comment: No, when the user himself changes it.

Comment: both from customer account in frontend?

Comment: yes the event gets fired

Comment: As per the core, it is not an event which was set for reset password, until someone sets the event on custom module, check your custom modules? Also if that's the case then check for observer in your custom module if someone that a observer for that event, default is \Magento\module-customer\Observer\AfterAddressSaveObserver.php, this was the correct one, which you can see has nothing to do with reset password.